# how can i return data from this.$http.get in vue js

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vue.js

Hi I'm having problem in returning a data in my ajax call using vue js in laravel 5. I have an array of state and call the function of ajax inside the loop. The problem now is it seems that the ajax cannot returned a value. here's my code:

```
ready: function() {

    var dData = {};

    for (var i=0; i<this.pState.selectedState.length; i++){
        dData = this.displayCounty(this.pState.selectedState[i])
    }
    console.log(dData);

},
methods:{

    displayCounty: function(val){
        var nData = {};

        // ajax get County list
        this.$http.get('/api/counties/' + val )
            .success(function(counties){
               return counties;
            })
            .error(function(){

            }) //ajaxcall

    }// displaCounty
}
```

any idea guys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to assign the returned results to a variable then try this:

```
ready: function() {
    this.getCounties;
},

data: {
    counties: []
},

methods:{

    getCounties: function(val){

        // ajax get County list
        this.$http.get('/api/counties/' + val )
            .success(function(counties){
               this.counties = counties;
            })
            .error(function(){

            }); //ajaxcall

    } // displayCounty
}
```

Comment: What I did is assign this to  a new variable like "var self = this" then in ajax i just assign the countries to self.countries and I can now get the values.

Comment: How about, if I don't want to assign that result to countries data?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the asynchronous nature of `$http.get`. The return you have of `return counties` is not going to effect the return value of `displayCounty`. `displayCounty` returns `null` immediately and the `return counties` later ends up doing nothing.

A good strategy to use in this case is to have the `success` callback set `counties` on the View Model. Then you can setup a watcher on `counties` and process the data whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ready has been replaced by Mounted in Vue.js 2

You should use this:

```
ready: mounted() {
    this.getCounties;
},
```